# How do I format my created_at output correctly with I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using [this I18n file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml).

I am calling it in my view like this:

```
<td class="center"><%= l o.created_at %></td>
```

This is being outputted like this:

```
Mon, 22 May 2013 04:04:43 +0000
```

For starters, why is it displaying `May 22, 2013` and not `April 22`?

When I do it in the console, I get this:

```
> o.created_at
 => Mon, 22 Apr 2013 04:04:43 UTC +00:00
```

I don't want it to display the time, or rather would prefer to just say something like:

```
Monday, April 22, 2013 @ 4:04am
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom date/time formats to your translation file. To see what time-based substitutions are possible, consult a reference for [strfime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
formats:
  default: ! '%Y-%m-%d'
  long: ! '%B %d, %Y'
  short: ! '%b %d'
  custom: ! '%A, %M %B, %Y @ %l:%M%P'
```

In your view, you'd make use as follows:

```
<%= l o.created_at, :format => :custom %>
```

You may need to get rid of blank entries in your en.yml file to correct your translation errors.

Comment: When I used that, I get this error: `: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (myapp/config/locales/en.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 39 column 1>` Where `line 39` is the `custom` line. Thoughts?

Comment: It means Psych, the yaml parser your Rails app is using, can't parse the token starting at line 39 of your yaml file. This often happens when making typos or copying & pasting code from the web. I can't tell without seeing your yaml file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, but I noticed your indent is off and you may need to add the "custom" bit to the `time` formats. What versions of Rails/Ruby/Psych are you using?

Comment: I am using Rails 3.2.12/Ruby 1.9.3/no clue Psych.

Comment: Try `Psych::VERSION` on the console

Comment: Wow....it is the spacing. I had tabbed and did 3 spaces and that seems to have been throwing it off. I finally got it working. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, I had to move it into the `Time` section, and am now getting `May` instead of `April`. But I have removed the empty `-` in the month_names. What could be causing it? Here is my updated YAML file - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/3c250178af9bf48e9a3d